# Time difference in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Im trying to figure out a way to get the time difference in seconds between two dates.

For example, difference in seconds between:

```
2013-5-11 8:37:18

2013-5-11 10:37:18
```

Tried:

```
function timeDifference(laterdate, earlierdate) {
    var difference = laterdate.getTime() - earlierdate.getTime();
    var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60/24);
    difference -= daysDifference*1000*60*60*24
    var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
    difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60
    var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);
    difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60
    var secondsDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000);

    return secondsDifference;
}
```

But that does not work in Nodejs, error with

> getTime()

function not being found

Comment: What are you passing to the function? Strings or date objects?

Comment: Im passing it strings

Comment: `npm install moment` -> `moment(laterdate).diff(earlierdate, 'days')`

Comment: Use moment (http://momentjs.com/), it'll change your life.

Comment: "seconds between two dates" <-> "I'm passing it strings". Uhm, what?

Comment: Yeah, strings don't have a `.getTime()` method. Anyway that function doesn't even calculate the total amount of seconds but the seconds part of the difference.

Comment: The code given here will work if you give Date objects as arguments instead of strings. you can create date objects using `new Date(laterdate)`

Answer (score 40):

```
var moment = require('moment')
var startDate = moment('2013-5-11 8:73:18', 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss')
var endDate = moment('2013-5-11 10:73:18', 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss')
var secondsDiff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds')
console.log(secondsDiff)
```

You will need the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) module

```
npm install -S moment
```

Comment: I think you need to add 

var secondsDiff = moment(endDate).diff(startDate, 'seconds')

Comment: `endDate.diff is not a function`

Comment: i think you need to install 'moment'

Answer (score 4):

The timezonecomplete module has support for date differences, even with dates in different time zones. It returns a Duration object which is unit-aware, not just a "number" that represents "milliseconds":

```
var tc = require("timezonecomplete");   

var start = new tc.DateTime("2014-06-26T12:00:00 Europe/Amsterdam");
var end = new tc.DateTime("2014-06-26T12:00:00 UTC");

var duration = end.diff(start);  // unit-aware duration

console.log(duration.minutes()); // -120
console.log(duration.hours()); // -2
```

Answer (score 3):

It will check the system time and find the difference.

```
var moment = require('moment')
var firstTime = moment();

setInterval(someTask,1000);
function someTask(){
  var secondTime = moment();
  var timeDifference = secondTime.diff(firstTime, 'seconds')
  console.log(timeDifference)
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set timeout on a loop as I did, you don't need to use momentjs at all. Try the following.

```js
let timeout = 3; //seconds
console.log("start:" + new Date());
let start = Number(Date.now());
let end = start + timeout * 1000;
while (Number(Date.now()) < end) {
  // your code here
}

console.log("end:" + new Date());
```

PS: I understand that this post does not quite answer the question asked, but this is the link popping up when you google 'time difference in nodejs'.

Answer (score 1):

Get the remaining days :

```
var moment = require('moment');

var startDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

var endDate = moment(new Date("Tue Aug 27 2015 09:13:40 GMT+0530 (IST)")).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

var remainingDate = moment(endDate).diff(startDate, 'days');

console.log(remainingDate) // at time of posting, 106 days
```

Comment: This appears to no longer be a valid answer: `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822
/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.` I bet it was a good answer for a long time, but now we are being discouraged from following this path. Isn't there something else? Should I re-ask this question?

Comment: This seems to be a better way to do it: Also does not give a Deprecation warning. `var minutesDiff = moment(recievedTimeStamp, 'HH:mm a').fromNow();`

Answer (score 1):

We can use this optimized code too,

```
function calculateDays(startDate,endDate)
{
   var start_date = moment(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   var end_date = moment(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   var duration = moment.duration(end_date.diff(start_date));
   var days = duration.asDays();       
   return days;
}
```

Here you need to install `moment` and want to import before using.

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
const MOMENT = require('moment');

const TimeDiff = ( startTime, endTime, format ) => {

    startTime = MOMENT( startTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' );
    endTime = MOMENT( endTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' );
    return endTime.diff( startTime, format);
}

let startTime = new Date('2013-5-11 8:37:18');
let endTime = new Date('2013-5-11 10:37:18');

console.log( TimeDiff(startTime, endTime, 'seconds'));
```