# How I can calculate an elapsed time between two date objects in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, ionic-framework

I have a date object created from vars saved in a database.

```
var prevdate = yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;
```

I want to calculate with current time (date now ()) and want show to list on my Ionic app like my concept below such as "2 days ago" or "A moment ago" or "One hour ago". How I can achieve it?

[image: Time Concept]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use http://momentjs.com/ for date manipulation using js. It provides most of the features we need related with date. You can get the date difference on moment using

```
moment('2015-06-24 19:57:00', "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

Comment: Thanks for angular user will better with [angular moment plugin](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/)

Comment: Its always better not using a plugin first, adding overhead that isnt needed is a big no when you are trying to keep things simple. Also its not easy adding moment.js to ionic apps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
var past=new Date('2015-06-24 19:57:00');
var now= new Date();
var diff=msToTime(now-past);

console.log(diff.toString());

function msToTime(s) {
  var ms = s % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;
  if(hrs==0 && mins==0)
      return 'just a moment ago';
  else if(hrs==0)
      return mins+' mins ago';
  else if(hrs<24)
      return hrs+' hours ago';
  else
      return Math.floor(hrs/24)+' days ago';
}
```

Try out changing out the past var to see various results.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of time delta.
[Time difference in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495368/time-difference-in-nodejs)

then create a function as previous answer suggested to make decision on what to return as string.